# split string with regex expresion on bash dont work

Tags: regex, bash

I can split the next string

```
     1 - Tiendas HD StoreID,SellerID,Country,Flag,StoreName,Address,City,Latitude,Longitude,postalCode,state,localNumber,referenceLocation,businessUnit,fantasyName,legalName,alternativeId,assigneeDocumentNumber,assigneeDocumentType,assigneeEmail,assigneePhone,externalId,initHour,endHour,active,additionalData N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" 
                       2 - Tiendas RT StoreID,SellerID,Country,Flag,StoreName,Address,City,Latitude,Longitude,postalCode,state,localNumber,referenceLocation,businessUnit,fantasyName,legalName,alternativeId,assigneeDocumentNumber,assigneeDocumentType,assigneeEmail,assigneePhone,externalId,initHour,endHour,active,additionalData N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}"
```

I want split this string with  by `"$number -"`, example

```
"1 - text a"
```

Or

```
"1
2 - text b"
```

to take the follow result

```
"text a" 
"text b"
```

I have the next code

```bash
s=' 
             1 - Tiendas HD StoreID,SellerID,Country,Flag,StoreName,Address,City,Latitude,Longitude,postalCode,state,localNumber,referenceLocation,businessUnit,fantasyName,legalName,alternativeId,assigneeDocumentNumber,assigneeDocumentType,assigneeEmail,assigneePhone,externalId,initHour,endHour,active,additionalData N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}" 
                               2 - Tiendas RT StoreID,SellerID,Country,Flag,StoreName,Address,City,Latitude,Longitude,postalCode,state,localNumber,referenceLocation,businessUnit,fantasyName,legalName,alternativeId,assigneeDocumentNumber,assigneeDocumentType,assigneeEmail,assigneePhone,externalId,initHour,endHour,active,additionalData N001,1,Chile,Nike,Nike Las Condes,"Av. Pdte. Kennedy Lateral 9001, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana",Santiago,35.3333,21.2222,788977,Santiago,53A,frente al Easy,HD,Nike HD Kennedy,Nike LF Store LLC,N205,20833673‑8,RUT,feliperuiz@cencosud.com,569888777,vtexnikeqa001,09:00,20:00,1,"{ propety1: 3272, propetyN: ""default"",}"'


#String
text=$s
input=$text
IFS='([0-9 ]*[-] +)|(\s\s+[0-9 ]*[-] +)' array=($input)
for element in "${array[@]}"; 
do
    echo "--->  $element" ;
done
```

Replit
https://replit.com/@JoseCastillo20/BASH#main.sh

Comment: `$IFS` is not interpreted as a regex. It's just a list of characters.

Comment: you can gimme one example please ?

Comment: `(IFS=ab ; read x y z <<< "xaybz" ; echo "$x, $y, $z")` outputs `x, y, z`.

Comment: I added some triple-backticks in your question so that the identation of what's in between is taken "as is". Please edit your post so that what we can see conforms to reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a string on regex pattern, would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

s='
     1 - text a
            2 - text b
'
pat='[[:space:]]*[0-9]+ -'              # pattern to split on

# loop to split the string
while [[ $s =~ ^(.*)$pat(.*)$ ]]; do
    array+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]%"${BASH_REMATCH[2]##*[![:space:]]}"}" )
    s="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"              # update "s" with the remaining substring
done

# print the array elements
for (( i = ${#array[@]} - 1; i >= 0; i-- )); do
    echo "--->  ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
--->   text a
--->   text b
```

- The `[[ $s =~ ^(.*)$pat(.*)$ ]]` condition splits `$s` on the pattern `$pat`
  assigning `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to the left substring and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`
  to the right wrt the pattern. Due to the nature of `longest match`
  of regex, the last element `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` is determined first, while
  `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` still may contain other patterns to be matched.
- Then `s` is updated with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, the left substring, and
  the `while` loop continues until no more matches remain.
- `${BASH_REMATCH[2]%"${BASH_REMATCH[2]##*[![:space:]]}"}` removes trailing
  space characters (whitespces, tabs, newlines, etc.) out of `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.
- As the array holds the elements in reverse order, the `for` loop prints
  the elements from the last to the first.

Answer (score 0):

`$IFS` is not interpreted as a regex, but as a list of characters.